# How to generate a minute level time range for last 10 days in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery, timestamp, date-range

For instance:

```
WITH 
CTE_DATE_RANGE AS (
              SELECT
                *
              FROM
              UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(CURRENT_DATE()-20, CURRENT_DATE())) as date
               )
select
 *
FROM
CTE_DATE_RANGE
```

gives me a date range for the last 20 days.
But I want this data at a minute level for the last x number of days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to generate a minute level time range for last 10 days in BigQuery?

You might consider using [`GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#generate_timestamp_array) function.

```sql
  SELECT *
    FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(
      TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE - 9),
      TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE + 1), DAY) - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE,
      INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
    )) AS date_time;
```

- output will be from `2022-11-28 00:00:00 UTC` to `2022-12-07 23:59:00 UTC` for last 10 days including today.